# Global Temporary Table Creation Failed

Tags: php, mysql

i have some link which show data on iframe with the help of temporary data from database
i am fetching this data with the help of query strings

the page with Links is

```
    <style type="text/css">
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.Menu
{
    width:150px;
    float:left;
}
.fr
{
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
    float:right
}

</style>
<div class="Menu">
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$sql="select * from NSEIndices_latest";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$tpnt=$row['TickerPlantCode'];  //nse indice code
$indexname=$row['IndexName']; //nse indice index name
?>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://mastertrade.in/master/wpfiles/gtnsegainers.php?tpnt=<?php echo $tpnt;?>&indexname=<?php echo $indexname;?>" target="fr"><?php echo $indexname;?></a><br></td>
  </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
    <div class="fr">
    <iframe height="780" width="780" scrolling="no" name="fr"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Now the link from above page fetch data with the help of query string at this page a temporary table is created by collectiong data from various tables
but am getting error while retrieve data from that temporary table

the page with temporary table is

```
    <table class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Company Name
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">High
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Low
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Last Price
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Prv Close
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">Change
      </th>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border:#e7e7e7 1px solid; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-color:#f9f9f9;">%Gain
      </th>
  </tr>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$tpnt=$_GET['tpnt'];
$indexname=$_GET['indexname'];
echo "1".$indexname. "<br>";
$query="SELECT nsepricequotes_latest.Symbol, nsepricequotes_latest.CompanyName, nsepricequotes_latest.HighPrice, nsepricequotes_latest.LowPrice, nsepricequotes_latest.LastTradedPrice, nsepricequotes_latest.ClosePrice, nsepricequotes_latest.NetChange, nsepricequotes_latest.PercentChange, nse_index_constituents.Tickerplant_index_code,nse_index_constituents.NSE_Index_Name
FROM nsepricequotes_latest, nse_index_constituents
WHERE nsepricequotes_latest.TickerPlantCode = nse_index_constituents.TickerPlant_scrip
AND PercentChange >0
ORDER BY PercentChange DESC ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo "2".$indexname. "<br>";
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$Symbol1=$row1['Symbol'];
$CompanyName1=$row1['CompanyName'];
$HighPrice1=$row1['HighPrice'];
$LowPrice1=$row1['LowPrice'];
$LastTradedPrice1=$row1['LastTradedPrice'];
$ClosePrice1=$row1['ClosePrice'];
$NetChange1=$row1['NetChange'];
$PercentChange1=$row1['PercentChange'];
$Tickerplant_index_code1=$row1['Tockerplant_index_code1'];
$NSE_Index_Name1=$row1['NSE_Index_Name'];
}
echo "3".$indexname. "<br>";
$tbl="create GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temppice(Symbol varchar(100),CompanyName varchar(200),HighPrice float(50),LowPrice float(50),LastTradedPrice float(50),ClosePrice float(50),NetChange float(50),PercentChange float(50),Tickerplant_index_code varchar(100),NSe_Index_Name varchar(100)) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;";
$res=mysql_query($tbl);
if (!$res) { die('Temporary table creation failed: ' . mysql_error()); }
if(mysql_error())die(mysql_error());
$intbl="Insert into temppice values('$Symbol1','$CompanyName1','$HighPrice1','$LowPrice1','$LastTradedPrice','$ClosePrice1','$NetChange1','$PercentChange1','$Tockerplant_index_code1','$NSE_Index_Name1')";
mysql_query($intbl);
if(mysql_error())die(mysql_error());
echo "4".$indexname. "<br>";
$query1="Select * from temppice where NSE_Index_Name=$indexname";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);
//if(mysql_error())die(mysql_error());
mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_BOTH))
{
$symbol=$row['Symbol'];  
$CompanyName=$row['CompanyName'];
$HighPrice=$row['HighPrice'];
$LowPrice=$row['LowPrice'];
$previousclose=$row['LastTradedPrice'];
$ClosePrice=$row['ClosePrice'];
$netChange=$row['NetChange'];
$percentagechange=$row['PercentChange'];
?>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $CompanyName;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $HighPrice;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $LowPrice;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $previousclose; ?></td>
   <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $ClosePrice;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $netChange;?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-right:#e7e7e7 1px solid; border-left:#e7e7e7 1px solid ;border-bottom:#e7e7e7 1px solid;"><?php echo $percentagechange;?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

the error am getting is

> Temporary table creation failed: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE
>   temppice(Symbol varchar(100),CompanyName varchar(200),Hig' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

[According to the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) the MySQL `CREATE TABLE` syntax does not support the `global` keyword.  That [appears to be an Oracle thing](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/TemporaryTables.php).  Likewise I believe that the `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` clause is part of the Oracle syntax which will not work in MySQL either.

If you remove those two parts it will probably work:

```
 $tbl=<<<SQL
create TEMPORARY TABLE temppice (
    Symbol                 varchar(100),
    CompanyName            varchar(200),
    HighPrice              float(50),
    LowPrice               float(50),
    LastTradedPrice        float(50),
    ClosePrice             float(50),
    NetChange              float(50),
    PercentChange          float(50),
    Tickerplant_index_code varchar(100),
    NSe_Index_Name         varchar(100)
);
SQL;
```

Comment: I don't think I see any other problems with the syntax of that statement.  Are you sure you are getting the _exact same_ error? Is it still saying `near 'GLOBAL TEMORARY TABLE`?  If so are you sure you removed that part of the statement? Could it be hitting another instance of the unsupported syntax later somewhere else in the code?